# Buefy, Vuex, Toast: could not find declaration file

Tags: vuex, buefy

I want to use Toast to show a message from my store. 
According to the documentation I have to

```
import { Toast } from 'buefy/dist/components/toast';
```

but then typescript warns:

> Could not find a declaration file for module 'buefy/dist/components/toast/index.js'

When I import Toast as

```
import { Toast } from 'buefy'
```

typescript seems to be satisfied, but the Toast doesn't work.

Comment: For reference: since Buefy recognizes Toast (The definition file is imported with the global `Vue.use(Buefy);`) I just let Typescript ignore the "missing" declaration file for that line with `// @ts-ignore`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version of Buefy you use? Last version change import statment for Toast, Modal...
You have to do that [since v0.8.0](https://github.com/buefy/buefy/releases/tag/v0.8.0):

```
import { ToastProgrammatic as Toast } from 'buefy'
Toast.open('Toasty!')
```

https://buefy.org/documentation/toast#from-outside-vue-instance